# How do I symbol numbers into groups?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, legend, symbology

I am working on creating soils map and need to group symbolize into greater numbers and within between numbers..

Here is an example of what I am talking about ...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you should use a **[graduated color renderer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Using_graduated_colors/00s500000029000000/)**:

> The graduated color renderer is one of the common renderer types used
>   to represent quantitative information—especially for polygon feature
>   classes. Using a graduated colors renderer, the quantitative values
>   for a field are grouped into ordered classes. Within a class, all
>   features are drawn with the same color. Each class is assigned a
>   graduated color from smallest to largest.

To get the legend labels looking exactly as in your graphic, once you have performed your classification, just type over them in the Symbology tab of the Legend Properties (or in the Table of Contents).

Comment: Thank you. I got it and got it the numbers what I wanted.